# Q: AWS Beanstalk default domain wildcard cname prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I would like to have wildcard domains for an auto-scaling application running on AWS Beanstalk.

I cannot use a custom domain with Route53 or alternatives, so I am forced to use the default generated domain format, eg: `environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

I would like to have something like this `*.environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` configured at the load balancer level for my setup.

Does anyone know if there is a way to specify a wildcard domain prefix for the beanstalk applications running with the default domain?

Comment: but `environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` is load balander already. Why you need set a EBL in front of it?

Comment: I am not adding an extra EBL, one is already added by elastic beanstalk for the auto-scaling to work. I just need to modify that EBL to support a wildcard CNAME or do something else to make wildcards work with the default beanstalk domain.

Comment: I still didn't get it. `environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` is CNAME only. What do you need for `*.environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com`?

Comment: I need `a.environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com`, `b.environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` ... `*.environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` to point to the same ELB to which `environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` points to. I think the easiest way for this would be to add a CNAME from `*.environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` pointing to `environment-name.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

Comment: great, you got answer already.